# Did I choose well my verbs tenses?

Tags: tense

this is Yves: remember me ! I was (and still is a big fan of FOAO. )

We **had first met** in Rouen for a concert  and then  we **had  kept** in touch for a long time  until the group FOAO split . May be you remember that during that period I  **had always asked** you "if there was a new release out soon."

Just would like two know if the tenses chosen are idiomatic

I  used past perfect for met because it happened before I was a fan , I also chose it for had kept because it lasted a long time and finished when the band split about 10 or 20 years ago now. I did the same for" had always asked" because it happened during the band was active and stopped after .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Question about usage of a past perfect tense in a particular sentence](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/294401/question-about-usage-of-a-past-perfect-tense-in-a-particular-sentence)

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason to use past perfect just because one event occurred before another event.  So in all these cases, there is no reason to use past perfect.  Past tense would be better.

It might be possible to say:  "We'd first met in Rouen for a concert, but we became friends when we met up in Paris.... (the rest of the paragraph is about the time in Paris)" That works because the first meeting was complete at the time you are writing about. But even in that situation, the simple past tense would also work as well or better.

Comment: You only use the past perfect in this way _when you are telling a story in the past tense and need to refer to something that happened before the time frame of the story._

Comment: but I am not really telling a story and I thought that using past simple for the first verb meet could be ambiguous, did it happen before or after I was a big fan?  I thought by using past perfect it would  not  be ambiguous anymore both events(the meeting and the touch °  clearly happened before  I was a big fan . I was wrong but did not understand why ;

Comment: You are telling a story (the story of how we met, its a non-fictional narrative) There is no obvious connection to "when you became a fan of foma", so past perfect or simple past, I'd assume that you were always a fan.  I don't see this as an ambiguity, Just something that is not given in the monologue.

Comment: I became a fan  because I saw him and his group playing in Rouen and because I started keeping in touch. So  in my mind there was a connection between these 2 event and becoming a fan   .